# How to perform erase for spi nor flash using j flash spi

Tags: flash

I have a spi nor flash MX25V8035F which is not supported as auto detect for j flash spi. So i manully connect. I'm able to read/erase the flash but some region of the flash is protected. How can i perform a full erase including the protected memory region ?

I looked at the data sheet MX25V8035F and it looks like you have to perform serial of operation in order to unprotect the memory but i don't see any options on j flash spi exe or the command line of j flash spi where i can send custom data commands.